# A pergunta "Erro ao retornar endereço do CLGeocorder" é descontextualizada?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Temos esta pergunta [Erro ao retornar endereço do CLGeocorder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16857/7210) a ser votada para fechar como descontextualizada, no SOEN a mesma pergunta [Error return address CLGeocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23819466/1817673) está protegida pela comunidade.

Eu sinceramente olhei, e não sei o que fazer. A pergunta poderá ser pertinente para muita gente, ao mesmo tempo como já foi resolvido o problema, será que se justifica manter? Ou fecha-se?

Comment: "Está protegida pela comunidade" não é algo positivo. [**What is a protected question?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question): "The system (via the Community user) will automatically protect a question that's had three answers from low-rep users deleted or 5 answers from low-rep users posted in the past 24 hours."

Comment: Na minha opinião seu título está em desacordo com o corpo da sua pergunta, respondendo apenas ao seu título: Por mais que uma pergunta seja interessante ela deve ser fechada caso seja descontextualizada, entretanto não é o caso da pergunta que você linkou.

Comment: @Math o titulo da pergunta vem de encontro dos motivos para fechar que vi na analise. Se quiseres editar e sugerir um titulo.

Comment: `como já foi resolvido o problema, será que se justifica manter? Ou fecha-se?` imagina se fechássemos todas as perguntas que foram resolvidas? rsrs.. como eu disse no comentário da única resposta até o momento, não temos como prever se o erro não se acontecerá novamente ou não. Eu votei par deixar aberta.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal pergunta protegida não é algo positivo nem negativo, significa apenas que atraiu muitos usuários novatos. Eu acho que essa pergunta foi muito bem recebida no SOEN, já que ela possui 8 votos a favor e 4 usuários favoritaram.

Comment: [Cross-post no Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256332/a-server-goes-down-affecting-many-developers-is-the-question-on-topic)

Comment: @brasofilo uma tradução livre é que era ;)

Answer (score 7):

Também não entendo nada do assunto. Me parece *too localized*.

## O que fazer com algo tão localizado no tempo mas ao mesmo tempo potencialmente útil para várias pessoas?

Deixe sobreviver localizada no tempo. Mantenha aberta para produzir respostas úteis e depois feche e deixe no site por motivos históricos.

Vamos tentar ajudar as pessoas que estão precisando da ajuda sem prejudicar a filosofia do site. Nós podemos ter as duas coisas. Após termos uma resposta, deixamos claro que não é uma pergunta que merece maiores interações.

Só sei que no momento pode ajudar alguém, não sei se vai ajudar no futuro ou não. Eu não tenho certeza se é muito localizada no tempo. Portanto para esta pergunta específica eu não estou recomendando fechar depois. Avalie quem tem condição de avaliar. Mas se você não tem condição, por favor, se abstenha.

## Se se esquecermos de fechar depois?

Paciência. Não vai matar o site. Se esquecermos é porque não era problema real.

## E se aparecer um monte de coisa assim?

Eu acho que já aparece coisa pior. Se aparecer muita coisa assim e estiver causando problemas, revemos o assunto.

Quero relembrar que estamos em uma nova fase do site e até tivemos tão poucos problemas que não sei nem se pode dar essa nomenclatura. Acho que chegou a hora de aceitarmos um pouco mais de coisas que podem ajudar mais que prejudicar. Não vamos abrir demais também.

Se alguém discorda, demonstre porque o mal é maior que o benefício. Só especular que no futuro pode trazer problemas, acredito que não seja mais válido, **passamos da fase de definição do site**.

Não gostava da ideia inicial do "deixe para depois o que não está causando problema" no início do site. Todos os outros sites foram definidos com muito cuidado. De fato a comunidade abraçou a causa do cuidado inicial. Agora é hora de mudar isto. Agora podemos paulatinamente soltando as rédeas com cuidado.

Perguntas sem qualidade e que não se encaixe de verdade na ferramenta que temos ainda não são permitidas.

Comment: Deixar aberta e *sem resposta*, como está agora, também não acrescenta muito. Espero que alguém responda, depois desse auê todo.

Comment: O problema é que a janela de tempo para uma resposta útil já passou. A resposta é “Erro temporário nos servidores da Apple”.

Comment: @bfavaretto estou pensando muito sobre todas as perguntas sem resposta mas ainda não cheguei em uma conclusão. Quando eu tiver algo interessante para falar sobre isso, vou postar algo. O que posso adiantar é que se a pergunta é localizada e não há solução em algum tempo, é melhor fechar mesmo.

Comment: @Bavarious você pode ter razão mesmo. Não vou entrar no mérito específico dela porque desconheço completamente o assunto e não quero correr o risco de dizer algo que parece ser certo e não ser. Outras pessoas com melhor qualificação para o assunto, ao que parece você é uma delas, podem decidir isto.

Comment: @Bavarious “Erro temporário nos servidores da Apple” + link para anúncio oficial da Apple + fechar a pergunta. Pronto.

Comment: Como era a resposta do autor da pergunta, que ele diz que deletou? Igual a do SOen? Pode-se votar pra fazer *undelete*? Não é minha área tampouco, mas, se é um erro HTTP 500, parece muito óbvio que o problema não é no código... Enfim, espero que o caso sirva pra assentar ou ajudar a formar jurisprudência aqui no SOPT.

Comment: @brasofilo Deve ter sido um comentário, não tem nenhuma resposta deletada na pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Essa pergunta pode ser interpretada como restrita a um curto espaço de tempo. Na época em que usava mais o Stack Overflow, havia uma opção de fechamento chamada *too localized* para esse caso. Aparentemente, essa opção agora faz parte de *off topic* mesmo: veja a pergunta [Where did “too localized” go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go) no meta.SO.

Answer (score 3):

Não entendo coisa alguma sobre o tema da pergunta, mas a meu ver não há nada nela que a torne descontextualizada. É o caso clássido do "eu tenho um código, ele não funciona como eu esperava, por que?". O fato de a resposta ser "problema no servidor da Apple e não no seu código" não faz da pergunta inválida. Ela tem que ser analizada em isolamento, considerando o que foi escrito ali.

Sendo assim, não há motivo nenhum para fechar. Embora seja verdade a resposta esteja presa no passado e muito provavelmente não seja útil no futuro.

Comment: Eu votei para deixá-la aberta. Não tem como prevermos o futuro, um erro idêntico pode acontecer amanhã ou depois, simplesmente não sabemos.

Comment: @Math, **P:** *"Tem um servidor de terceiros que está off-line e meu código não funciona, que posso fazer?"* **R:** *"Sei lá... um Twitter, um pedido de ajuda no fórum do terceiro, uma bat-macumba..."*. Uma pergunta no SO não vai servir pra nada mais além de confirmar »é, deu pau« e pra ninguém mais fora daquela faixa horária que o servidor deu pau.

Comment: @brasofilo resposta correta: espera :)
O problema é que a mensagem de erro não foi: `o servidor remoto está fora`, foi um baita errão

Answer (score 1):

Iniciei os votos para fechar pois tinha pedido ao Autor da Pergunta manternos informados do que acontecesse no SO, <strike>e isso não aconteceu</strike> (vejo agora que o OP diz haver postado uma resposta porém a removeu).

Nas [respostas e comentário feitos no Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819466/error-return-address-clgeocoder), tudo indica que seja um problema nos servidores da Apple e não algo relacionado à programação, e por esse motivo creio que **sim, é descontextualizada**.

A pergunta no SO foi protegida porque gerou [várias respostas que foram deletadas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC1Gz.jpg) ao serem sinalizadas como "baixa qualidade":

Entendo que tenha muitos votos positivos e tanto movimento (428 visitas em 3 dias) como sinal de que a falha nos servidores da empresa afetou muitos programadores.

Comment: Não respondeste a pergunta...

Comment: @JorgeB., whoopsie, tens toda razão, construi meu argumento mas não explicitei a conclusão. Atualizado.